# Eclipse project and Maven pom file not in same directory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have a project in Eclipse for which the Pom file(pom.xml) and Eclipse project file(.project) are not in the same directory. The Pom file is next to the source code.

The project resources in Eclipse are defined as Linked Resources(http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-13.htm).
I added the pom file as a Linked Resource then and converted the project in Eclipse to a Maven project(Configure -> Convert to Maven Project).

Unfortunately Eclipse is not showing the Maven Dependencies for that project and these are not resolved. Just having the Eclipse project file next to the pom and resources works well for that project but I cannot eventually use it(it's a company rule).

Tanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: What is the reason to locate the pom file into a different location than the source code which is the root of the project...and the `.project` files etc. will be generated during the import into Eclipse...

Comment: _"Just having the Eclipse project file next to the pom and resources works well for that project but I cannot eventually use it(it's a company rule)."_ I don't understand that: the eclipse project files are your persinal files located on your personal PC. nobody else sees them. Why are you following such a useless rule?

Comment: It is just that we are sharing the project files under version control but not next to the source code. I did not choose that :-/

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately Eclipse is not showing the Maven Dependencies for that
>   project and these are not resolved.

Yeah, and I believe that the Eclipse project files are ***not*** going to pick up your changes when you convert to a maven project. This is simply the way maven works because you have the `.project` file elsewhere.

One note may be helpful: it is generally considered bad practice to check in your `.project` & `.classpath` files into src control, no matter where they are located. Can you try and have those files removed from source control and generated for each developer locally.

Personally, I always do that when I first create the Eclipse workspace by creating my project from the pom file: `File -> import -> Existing Maven Project` and then I browse to the pom.xml file. My understanding is that this is (for many) the preferred way to create the java project in Eclipse.